# std::string causing memory leaks

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, stl, valgrind

I am running into a situation where my application is having memory leaks. After running valgrind, it looks as if I am getting a memory leak related to a std::string:

```
 ==20274== 34 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 34 of 140
 ==20274==    at 0x4C29DB5: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:332)
 ==20274==    by 0x7F843C8: std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned long, unsigned long, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
 ==20274==    by 0x7F84DE4: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
 ==20274==    by 0x7F84F32: std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
 ==20274==    by 0xA50CC71: __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int) (filename.cpp:22)
 ==20274==    by 0xA50D03F: _GLOBAL__sub_I_filename.cpp (filename.cpp:112)
 ==20274==    by 0x400E9CE: _dl_init (in /lib64/ld-2.12.so)
 ==20274==    by 0x4000B69: ??? (in /lib64/ld-2.12.so)
```

The code in question is:

in filename.h:

```
 extern std::string aString;
```

in filename.cpp:

```
 std::string aString = "a string";
```

Also worth note, this is in a separate namespace i.e.

```
 namespace aNamespace {
      //...
      std::string aString; // in extern in .h
      //...
 }
```

Every place in code, it is (of course) referenced as:

```
 aNamespace::aString;
```

And, from what I can tell, it is never reset, and is used either as a constant reference, or to initialize another string.

Can there ever be a situation where std::string would give memory leaks?

edit:

A related portion of the valgrind output:

```
 ==20274==    by 0x400EFBB: _dl_fini (in /lib64/ld-2.12.so)
 ==20274==    by 0x88DAA01: exit (in /lib64/libc-2.12.so)
 ==20274==    by 0x88C3D26: (below main) (in /lib64/libc-2.12.so)
```

Is this making an exit call? Is it the standard exit(0)?

Comment: I assume the program exited rather than crashed/aborted?

Comment: What implementation of std::string are you using?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?  `std::string` shouldn't leak as tat would break a lot of code bases.

Comment: Note valgrind can report leak from `std::string` if other object containing `std::string` is leaking. Inspect valgrind logs if there is other object which leaks. Fix that and do check again.

Comment: Also if you are using gcc or clang use address sanitizer, it is faster, more effective and reports are easier to understand.

Comment: @FireLancer yes, there was no crash

Comment: @NeilButterworth just your standard std::string

Comment: Yes, but what implementation of it - GCC, VC++, something else? Which language system and which version of that system.

Comment: @NeilButterworth ahh ok, misunderstood. GCC 4.8, linux (both centos 6/7, and ubuntu 14/16)

Comment: As @NathanOliver said we need a minimal, complete, and verifiable example. Valgrind is telling you the error is in file name.cpp but we only have a few snippets. As others have pointed out, if you create an object with a std::string and it is not destroyed Valgrind will report the string allocation and trace the stack up.

Comment: @Richard i am not sure what that additionally means here. it would be rather tedious to try to list out every place it is referenced, if that is what you mean

Comment: @basil What we need is something we can copy and paste into our own compilers that exhibits the memory leak.  Right now all we can tell you is it is more than likely not `std::string`'s fault.

Answer (score 0):

Valgrind produces this kind of messages if on program termination there's still some heap-allocated memory, but no variable holds a pointer to.
std::string allocates memory in it's constructor to provide storage for chars. Destructor should free memory back.

My guess is that application is terminated using exit(0) or so. In this case stack does not unwind, and no destructors are called.

Comment: I edited to include a related error, I think you may be right.